# After Upgrading from 12.04.to 12.10 will i have to install my drivers again?

Tags: drivers, upgrade, repository

I want to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 but will i have to install the broadcom drivers and some softwares that i installed from backtrack repository??

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't mix repositories! BackTrack is no longer supported by their creators which recommends the use of [Kali](http://kali.org). And no, *normally* you don't have to reinstall your drivers, *unless you built them from source* with options not included in the default installations, which is this case.